# Do I not understand Nuget Get-Package Syntax?

Tags: nuget

[image]

This should return a list of all versions right?

Nuget.org, my package source, hosts a lot of versions for this package.

[Here they are.](https://www.nuget.org/packages/angularjs.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped/)

Can someone tell me what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The -AllVersions parameter is part of the "Remote" parameter set which includes your parameters so it looks like the parameters are correct.

Looking at the request that is returned from https://nuget.org/api/v2/Search() it does not look like what you are trying to do is supported.

The raw data sent back does not include multiple versions for each NuGet package so, even though there is code in NuGet which does not collapse the versions down to the latest when -AllVersions is specified as it displays the results, you only get the one version for each NuGet package.

The -AllVersions parameter seems to only work when the -Updates parameter is used. This uses a different query https://nuget.org/api/v2/GetUpdates() which returns multiple package versions. So you can only see all NuGet package versions for the updated packages in your project.

```
    Get-Package -AllVersions -Updates -Filter jquery
```

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. Code for something which will never happen. I wonder if at some point, they changed the return value to only include the current version?

Comment: Quite possibly. It may be that new v2 api was optimized for the search you normally do from the Manage Packages dialog. That dialog only shows the latest version.